# AppBar disappears when I run the project on android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, appbar, bottom-navigation-bar

```
Need your assistance.

I'm finding it hard to display the Appbar when the bottom navigation bar is there. When I have them both, the appbar disappears when I run the app but when I remove the bottomnavbar, the Appbar becomes visible. How can I resolve this? This happens to all new dart files I create that I want to include an appbar.

I created a widget for the bottomnavbar on a different dart file. See code below: PS, Adding an appbar to this code below works well but not the other files where I have different appbars and calling the bottomnavbar like this: bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:salomon_bottom_bar/salomon_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:tikosocial/constants.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomNavBar> createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  var currentIndex=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.15),
                blurRadius: 30,
                offset: const Offset(0, 10),
              ),
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          child: SalomonBottomBar(
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            onTap: (i) => setState(() => currentIndex = i),
            items: [
              /// Home
              SalomonBottomBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.home_max_outlined),
                title: const Text("Home"),
                selectedColor: kHomeColor,
              ),

              /// Ticket
              SalomonBottomBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.local_activity_outlined),
                title: const Text("Ticket"),
                selectedColor: kPrimaryColor,
              ),

              /// Search
              SalomonBottomBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                title: const Text("Search"),
                selectedColor: kPrimaryColor,
              ),

              /// Profile
              SalomonBottomBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                title: const Text("Account"),
                selectedColor: kHomeColor,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}


But when I call it on a separate file only the bottomnavbar shows. See code sample below:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tikosocial/bottom_nav.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: const Row(

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried adding this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
```

```
But when I call it on a separate file only the bottomnavbar shows. See code sample below:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tikosocial/bottom_nav.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: const Row(

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

The above code will show the appbar If i remove the code: bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),. Adding it back will make the appbar disappear.